# Using Docker Secrets with Docker-Rootless & Docker Compose

Tags: docker

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 running docker-rootless with docker-compose 2.2.3

**Problem**

Can't use Docker Secrets with Docker Compose 2.2.3  **without** creating a swarm

**OS Version/build - Docker**
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           20.10.13
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.16.15
Git commit:        a224086
Built:             Thu Mar 10 14:07:51 2022
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default
Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          20.10.13
API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.16.15
Git commit:       906f57f
Built:            Thu Mar 10 14:05:44 2022
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
containerd:
Version:          1.5.10
GitCommit:        2a1d4dbdb2a1030dc5b01e96fb110a9d9f150ecc
runc:
Version:          1.0.3
GitCommit:        v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba
docker-init:
Version:          0.19.0
GitCommit:        de40ad0

**OS Version/build - Docker Compose**''
Docker Compose version v2.2.3

**Steps to reproduce**

1.) Install docker-rootless & docker-compose according to documentation on ubuntu 20.04.4

2.) Then execute:

```
$ echo "nextcloud" | docker secret create mysql_database -
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

Based on reading, I thought that with Docker Compose 1.11  above that users can specify secrets in Docker Compose without using Swarm.

Is this a limitation of running docker compose with docker-rootless?   If it is not, How do I generate secrets to be used in docker-compose.yml?

Here's my current yaml:

```
version: '3.9'

secrets:
  mysql_password:  
    external: true
  mysql_user:
    external: true
  mysql_database:
    external: true
  mysql_root_password:
    external: true
  redis_host_password:
    external: true
#  smtp_password:
#    external: true

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  mariadb:
  redis:
  phpmyadmin:
  
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
      - mysql_password
      - mysql_database
      - mysql_user
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_root_password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/mysql_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=/run/secrets/mysql_database
      - MYSQL_USER=/run/secrets/mysql_user
    networks:
      - test-aym
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_root_password
    networks:
      - test-aym
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./redis/redis-conf:/var/lib/redis
      - ./redis/cache:/data
    networks:
      - test-aym
  
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
      - phpmyadmin
    secrets:
      - mysql_password
      - mysql_database
      - mysql_user
      - redis_host_password
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_database
      - MYSQL_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_user
      - MYSQL_HOST=mariadb
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_HOST_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/redis_host_passowrd
      - NEXTCLOUD_DATA_DIR=./private/data
      #- NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=asiliyamama.local
      #- TRUSTED_PROXIES=172.18.0.0/16
      - SMTP_HOST=
      - SMTP_SECURE= 
      - SMTP_PORT=
      - SMTP_AUTHTYPE=
      - SMTP_NAME=
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=
      - MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS= 
      - MAIL_DOMAIN=
    networks:
      - test-aym
    
 

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  redis:
  phpmyadmin:

networks:
  test-aym:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure that the container started by docker-compose.yml is running inside a swarm cluster, because according to [the official website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret_create/)

> This command works with the Swarm orchestrator

Second, If you are not in docker swarm, should create the cluster first,

- ref the [official docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/)

After that, check out the cluster node information. `docker node ls`

- You will get similar results, such as:

[image]

and go to the **leader node** of the swarm cluster. Create the secret and reference it in yout docker-compose.yml file

i'm sure ervrything will be fine.